# Anchor Element to Right Side of Grid in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having a little trouble with positioning in a grid. I have different makrup than the markup posted below but I thought I would write something new for the sake of clarity. My problem is that the button on the right side of the screen looks good but as I resize it, it moves. In my personal site it will even move outside of the container if I resize it. How would I anchor it to the right side of the grid so the distance of the button and the right edge of the grid always stays the same even when I resize my window?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="bg-secondary" style="padding: 40px 40px 60px;">

<div class="tab-content bg-white" >
<div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <h4>Get Started Using Whatever</h4>
                <p><span className="font-weight-bold">Step 1</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p><span className="font-weight-bold">Step 2</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p><span className="font-weight-bold">Step 3</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <Button color="primary">Authorize Whatever Account</Button>
              </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/166366/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know if it's because this is your simplified version of your layout or not, but you need a `container / container-fluid` class.

Secondly, the distance of the button and the right edge of the grid always stay the same? Did you mean you want the button to always float to the right? You can set the `text-align` of the column to right to achieve that. If you want the button to always on the right side of the screen, you can use `position:fixed / absolute;`.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
    <button class="text-primary"> ... </button>
</div>
```

Lastly, I don't know what language you came from, but please try to use standard html attributes, like `class` instead of `className` etc.

```
<p><span class="font-weight-bold">Step 1</span> ... </p>
<button class="text-primary"> ... </button>
```

**fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/qockpgt7/7/

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! When I try to add a margin-right to pull it away from the side it falls to the bottom under the text. Any idea why this happens?